# Can we apply endorsement policy of hyperledger fabric using hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Currently, I am using docker-compose yaml file provided as example (cloned from location mentioned on composer website) to setup fabric 1.0

If I would like to change endorsement policy of fabric 1.0, then Is it possible using composer?

Comment: No this is currently not possible. There is an issue
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1251
tracking this

Comment: Thank You David

Then, which policy is being used while deploying 'bna' file using composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David has mentioned in comment, Currently composer is not supporting way of applying endorsement policy while deploying 'bna' file.

Feature is under development, You can track here:  github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1251